# Removing passwords from terminal logs in CentOS 7

Tags: bash, command-history

Sometimes a user gives a typo when they are trying to give a password after typing a sensitive command, such as `su -` .  The user then will assume they are being given another password request, and will then thus type the root password in the command prompt, leaving it there in the logs.  I feel that such password references in the logs are a security risk, particularly the root password.

What specific tools and syntax can be used to remove any such passwords from the logs?

Comment: By “terminal logs”, you mean normal shell command history, right? Or are you refering to some unusual, deliberate feature like a keyboard logger or terminal output logger that you're running on this machine?

Comment: @Gilles I mean the shell command history.  Or any other place where the history of terminal input gets stored in a standard installation of CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are many options to do this that wouldn't also result in further exposing credentials to the inquisitive user.

For example, bash has has the option to automatically exclude 'commands' (or more specifically, 'entries') from being recorded in the history file by way of the `HISTIGNORE` variable, which is a colon-separated list of text matches (with globbing) to ignore. For example, you could add `myP4*` to the HISTIGNORE variable to have it exclude `myP455w0Rd` from being recorded, however that would expose the first part of the password to anyone who cares to look, who could then guess what that exclusion was for.

Alternatively, you could have a cron job that runs at a reasonably frequent interval that inspects and removes such entries from the `.bash_history` file (or equivalent for your shell), but again that could potentially expose the match (and thus what would satisfy that match) to anyone who cared to look (though somewhat more secure if it's a cronjob for root).

The best answer in this situation is to teach your users to be more careful with entering anything on the console; especially if they are users that you've trusted with root access to the machine! Think of the (somewhat modified) adage: "look twice, execute once" - if they're doing anything involving access to the system, security should already be on their minds!